# Most efficient way to initialize NumPy matrix with a function of coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

What is the most efficient way of initializing a NumPy matrix with the results of a function taking the coordinates as arguments?

Currently, I only know how to do it with a double loop, but I heard it's usually not optimal for NumPy matrices.

```
M = np.zeros((1000,1000))

for i in range(1000):
    for j in range(1000):
        M[i][j] = f(i,j) #where f is the desired function
```

Is there a better way to implement NumPy matrix with the results of an arbitrary function of coordinates?

I assume that the function does, in fact, depend on two arguments, ie. there are no functions g and h, for which `f(x,y) = h(x)g(y)`.
(original: `f(x,y) = h(g(x,y))`).

Comment: It depends if your function allows vectorization. Provide more details on how your function looks like

Comment: Can you function only work with scalar values of `i` and `j`?  So it has to be called one for each combination of values?  There are minor tweaks that might give a 2x speedup, but not much better.

Comment: Entirely dependent on `f`, so you'll have to post what `f` is to get any help..

Comment: Unless you post some information about the function, you are unlikely to get anything useful

Comment: You can perform vectorization if your function allows so. If you need unique values that are independent for each (i,j), then it may not be made faster. Have you looked up the [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/) docs ? I would suggest you to have a look at [np.apply_along_axis()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) and edit the question to add some more information about **f()**.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` doesn't help with speed.  It still iterates over all the other axes.

Comment: Editor: please reverse `f(x,y) = h(x)g(y)` to previous form. The question is not about f(x,y) being multiplicative, but being dependent on some function returning one-dimentional value based on coordinates.

Comment: I changed the last equation back, but I don't see what difference that makes.  What matters, in terms of execution speed and method, is whether the two arguments can be 2d arrays representing all data points, or whether they have to be scalars (one data point).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a serious mismatch between the question and accepted answer.  `fun` is not an arbitrary function of the coordinates.  It is a fully 'vectorized' one, one that accepts broadcastable arrays.

```
In [195]: def fun(i,j): return i*j-j**2
In [196]: 
In [196]: np.fromfunction(fun, (4,4))
Out[196]: 
array([[ 0., -1., -4., -9.],
       [ 0.,  0., -2., -6.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0., -3.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  2.,  0.]])
In [197]: fun(np.arange(4)[:,None], np.arange(4))
Out[197]: 
array([[ 0, -1, -4, -9],
       [ 0,  0, -2, -6],
       [ 0,  1,  0, -3],
       [ 0,  2,  2,  0]])
```

All `fromfunction` does is generate a full set of coordinates, and pass the resulting array(s) to your function:

```
In [199]: np.indices((4,4))
Out[199]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3]]])
```

`np.meshgrid` and `np.mgrid` could also be used to generate these coordinates.  A function that works with 2d arrays like this is not arbitrary.  It is, though, a highly desirable trait when working with `numpy`.

Your question, or maybe it's the lack of response to our questions, implies that `i` and `j` have to be scalar, and hence requiring that each `i,j` pair gets passed individually to the function.  For example `j` might be used in `math.sin(j)`, or the function has some `if` test on the `i` or `j` value.  In that case the `fromfunction` approach will fail.

Comment: Hey, no "accepted answer" for now :-( —፨— Seriously, thanks for heads up, I have edited my answer...